# Error relation not found

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp

I wanted to test my postgreSQL connected to xampp but when I want to try it only an error appears: 
**Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: relation "test" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM test ^ in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3**
I used the following code:

```
<?php
$connection=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres 
password=postgres") 
or die("Can't connect");
$result=pg_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM test");
echo $result;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct server, using the correct database, and selecting from the correct table?

Comment: Is test the name of the database or the name of the table? You are connecting to a database named test .... is the name of your table test also?

Comment: Yes, the db name is same as table name.